Two AM-GM Inequalities
I recently learned in my linear algebra class that the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue is always greater than or equal to its geometric multiplicity. This reminded me of the AM-GM inequality because it is comparing an 'algebraic' quantity with a 'geometric' quantity. Also, in both cases AM $\geq$ GM. Is this just a coincidence or are these inequalities related in some grand way?

The AM in AM-GM is an arithmetic mean, not an algebraic mean.

Both inequalities do compare an “algebraic” and “geometric” quantity, but they arise from different areas of mathematics and are not inherently related. Algebraic vs. geometric multiplicities are rooted in linear algebra while the AM-GM inequality stems from real analysis. As a result, their similarity is more coincidental than anything and there is no concrete mathematical link.
